# addEventHandler() in a loop has unexpected results

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I wasn't sure what to look for, so I couldn't find any previous questions on this topic, and Google didn't help much, either.

```
(function() {
    var element = function(str) {
        return document.getElementById(str);
        },

        parent = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].getElementsByTagName('li'),
        len = parent.length,

        slides = slides || [];

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        var link = parent[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0],
            slide = element(parent[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href').substr(1));


        if (addEventListener) {
            link.addEventListener('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                alert(slide.getAttribute('id'));
            });
        } else if (attachEvent) {

        }
    }

})();
```

So, in the above code, within the for loop, I attach an event to all the links (five of them) which should alert the ID of the slide they're pointing to (just for debugging purposes), however they all show the ID of the last slide. I also created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdyvf/) for you to see it in... Action.

I'm assuming I am messing up something relatively simple, I just can't figure out what.

Comment: The er, slides[] is left-overs from something I tried earlier to resolve the same issue, you can ignore it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables in javascript are function-scope even when you declare them inside a block. This loop creates a closure around the variable loop, but loop is reassigned on every iteration. By the time the loop is done, all the closures point to the last element in the array.

To fix this, scope the variable differently:

```
(function() {
    var element = function(str) {
        return document.getElementById(str);
        },

        parent = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].getElementsByTagName('li'),
        len = parent.length;

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        var link = parent[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0],
            slide = element(parent[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href').substr(1));


        if (addEventListener) {
            link.addEventListener('click', (function(slide){
                return function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert(slide.getAttribute('id'))
                }
            })(slide));
        } else if (attachEvent) {

        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: I think there's a bug in your code, but thanks for the reply. The textual part helped a lot!

Comment: Probably is... I didn't look at it too closely

Comment: There, I edited it, but someone apparently has to review it before it goes through.

Answer (score 3):

I have encoutered this bug before, it is related to the binding of the `slide`, which is very difficult to explain. Here is a fix.

```
link.addEventListener('click',
    (function(x) {
       return function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                alert(x.getAttribute('id'));
              }
     })(slide));
```