# Can you create a bunch of functions from an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

How would I do something along these line? Do I need to use new Function()?

```
var bunchOfFunctionNames = ["functions", "of", "functions"];

for (var i = 0; i < eventTypes.length; i++) {
    myObject.prototype[bunchOfFunctionNames[i]] = function() {
        // do some stuff
    };
};
```

Comment: That should work just fine, if you replace `eventTypes` with `bunchOfFunctionNames`.

Comment: Won't they all end up being exactly the same function?  Also, note that if you need to reference the variable "i" inside those function definitions, you'll need to do this differently.

Comment: @Pointy, how would I read I inside the function?

Comment: Well, the trick is that *all* of those functions will "share" the same variable "i" from their outer scope.  I'll provide an answer to the question because it's too hard to type it here :-)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317924/addeventhandler-in-a-loop-has-unexpected-results/

Answer (score 2):

In re: my comment about getting at the value of "i" in your function creation loop, the problem is going to be that "i" will be **shared** by all the functions.  In other words, there's just one "i" variable in the outer function (where the loop is), so if you reference "i" in the functions you're creating, well, it won't work out properly (probably).  All of them will see "i" as being the "length" of your array of names, because that's what it'll be at the end of the loop.

There are several ways to deal with that.  If you were a Scheme programmer at heart, you'd do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < eventTypes.length; i++) {
    myObject.prototype[bunchOfFunctionNames[i]] = (function(copy_of_i) {
        return function() {
            // do some stuff, merrily referencing "copy_of_i"
        }
    })(i);
};
```

That "anonymous" function inside the loop provides a new scope, so because "i" is passed in as a parameter (called "copy_of_i", even though I hate underscores in variable names), it's safe for the *real* function to use it.  The anonymous function *returns* the real function, so that's the function that ends up in the object prototype.

Another option would be to pull that anonymous function out of the loop:

```
function makeFunctionForName(i) {
  return function() {
    // do something, and now "i" is the parameter and "safe"
  };
}

for (var i = 0; i < eventTypes.length; i++) {
    myObject.prototype[bunchOfFunctionNames[i]] = makeFunctionForName(i);
}
```